# Shopping cart suggestions

Tags: php

I have a shopping cart and items are added to a session as follows.

```
array_push($_SESSION['cart'],sanitize($id));
```

This is fine for single options that have no sub-options. But if you had and order like, Espresso with milk and an English muffin it would look a bit like this.

```
 $_SESSION['0'] is 'Espresso'
 $_SESSION['1'] is 'Milk'
 $_SESSION['2'] is 'English Muffin'
```

or a deli menu

```
 $_SESSION['0'] is 'sandwich'
 $_SESSION['1'] is 'ham'
 $_SESSION['2'] is 'cheese'
 $_SESSION['3'] is 'tomato'
 $_SESSION['4'] is 'Coke'
```

and then the user wanted to delete the `sandwich` and keep the `coke` how would I delete all of the sandwich and it's options `sandwich`, `ham` , `cheese`, `tomato` when the user choses to delete sandwich? keeping in mind the sandwich options could vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to re-think how you're adding the items to the cart.  What I think would make more sense is to create an array and add that array to the cart.  If you have an item with multiple options, you would create it as:

```
$espresso = array("milk");
$sandwich = array("ham","cheese","tomato");

$cart = array("drink"=>$espresso, "sandwich"=>$sandwich);
$_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
```

Then you if somoene wanted to remove the drink, they could do:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']['drink']);
```

Or if you just wanted to remove cheese:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']['sandwich'][2]);
```

What would make the most sense would be to have objects that you can add and remove attributes to and then manipulate what is in your session using your object methods.

Comment: Used this but in javascript rather than php